# Programmatic Login fails when SSL enabled

Tags: login, programmatically, ssl

Magento 1.9.1

I'm using a PHP script to programatically login a customer by customer id. Below is a working cut down test script:

```
require '../../app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
// Initialize Magento
Mage::app('default');

$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
$customer->load('8'); //sample customer id
$mySession = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
$mySession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);

if ($mySession->isLoggedIn()) {
    $custSessionId = $mySession->getEncryptedSessionId();
    Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl() . '?SID=' . $custSessionId)->sendResponse();
}
```

This basically works fine and on redirect the SID is passed and the customer is logged in.

Problem: when I enable SSL throughout the site (and change the unsecure baseurl to HTTPS) then the customer is not logged in on redirect.

Aside from this login issue, HTTPS / SSL on the site is working fine when enabled.

Any suggestions of things to try/check?

My URL / Cookie settings:

[image]

The server is apache with PHP 5.5.30, no Varnish etc and caching is all off.

With SSL disabled, when passed across to the site the customer is logged in and 1 cookie is set:

adminhtml (not secure)

The SID matches the cookie value. All is fine, however, the session/basket etc is then lost later on when we do go to a secure page (checkout, my account etc)

With SSL enabled for the entire site, when passed across to the site the customer is not logged in and 3 cookies are set:

_cid (secure)
adminhtml (not secure)
adminhtml_cid (secure)

however, none of the cookies match the SID passed across (do new ones get created?)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this worked for me:
https://community.magento.com/t5/Version-Upgrades/Secure-cookie-flag/td-p/2997

Created a copy of the file in local code pool and commented out that section.

Hope this helps someone else in future.